# Clojure REPL: iterate next value one-by-one

Tags: python-3.x, clojure

Consider the Python code:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> c = itertools.count()
>>> next(c)
0
>>> next(c)
1
```

What is the equivalent experience in Clojure REPL?

(Sure, I can do:

```clj
(take 5 (iterate inc 0))

;; => (0 1 2 3 4)
```

I would like to know whether I can get the next iteration value indefinitely one by one.)

Comment: Sure you could do it with atoms, as others have already pointed out. But, I suggest not doing it. Clojure sequences give us the ability to iterate over things without mutating *anything*, using `first` and `rest`/`next`. This is one of the things that needs to be unlearned, if Clojure is your first language where everything is immutable by default.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to keep track of some sort of state for that, maybe using an `atom`. The corresponding Clojure code for `c = itertools.count()` could be

```
(def my-lazy-seq (range))
(def c (atom my-lazy-seq))
```

We define a helper function that we can call just like the Python `next` function:

```
(defn next! [x]
  (ffirst (swap-vals! x rest)))
```

And then we can call this function on `c` to do the stepping:

```
(next! c)
;; => 0

(next! c)
;; => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

i would wrap it to a function, to enclose the atom:

```
(defn one-by-one [data]
  (comp ffirst (partial swap-vals! (atom data) rest)))

user> (def xs (one-by-one (range)))

user> (xs)
;;=> 0
user> (xs)
;;=> 1
```